# How to calculate peaks and valleys with first and last element using Numpy in performant way?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find peaks and valleys in a single array and I have achieved this using the [link](https://tcoil.info/find-peaks-and-valleys-in-dataset-with-python/). However, `pv` does not include the first element and the last element. How can I do it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# example data with peaks:
x = np.linspace(-1,3,1000)
data = -0.1*np.cos(12*x)+ np.exp(-(1-x)**2)

#     ___ detection of local minimums and maximums ___

pv = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(data))).nonzero()[0] + 1
```

[image]

Comment: Just add `0` and `len(x) - 1` as values to the beginning and end of `pv`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data with peaks:
x = np.linspace(-1, 3, 1000)
data = -0.1 * np.cos(12 * x) + np.exp(-((1 - x) ** 2))

#     ___ detection of local minimums and maximums ___

pv = np.diff(np.sign(np.diff(data))).nonzero()[0] + 1
pv = np.concatenate(([0], pv, [len(x) - 1]))

plt.plot(x, data, c="black", zorder=1)
plt.scatter(x[pv][::2], data[pv][::2], c="red", zorder=2)
plt.scatter(x[pv][1::2], data[pv][1::2], c="blue", zorder=3)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Won't it duplicate if the first or last is considered as peak or valley. Ah!! Now, I feel I am dumb for the first element. However, not able to wrap my head on last element

Comment: No I don't think it would duplicate... it can't be a peak/valley if it's on the end. Python is zero-indexed so the starting index of an array is 0 and the final is 1 minus the number of elements (len(x) - 1).